# dynamically created bootstrap columns with different heights, float to left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider an unknown number of divs being created dynamically and styled using the bootstrap grid system. In this example, I'm using `col-sm-4` so after every third block, we move to a new row. The blocks (divs) can be different heights, which is determined by the content within.

This is where I run into the layout problem. When moving to a new row, I want the fourth block to float to the left. This only happens when the left most div in the row above is also the shortest. I have pictures to illustrate.

**Real Life:**

[image]

**The Dream:**

[image]

The "correct" way to do this would be to wrap every three in a `row` class I beleive, but I'm not sure how to do this with dynamic content (could probably hack it) or if there's an easy css solution.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <div class="inner-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <div class="inner-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <div class="inner-block" style="height:150px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 block">
      <div class="inner-block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.block {
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner-block {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uk2GxnWGi3aNkfDKe7qY?p=preview) (expand preview to proper size)

Comment: This is the way floats work. http://salvattore.com/

Comment: You can also use http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ version 1 combined with https://github.com/cubica/isotope-sloppy-masonry to use it with Bootstrap columns.

Answer (score 6):

If your system is unable to add first/last classes on every nth div, then you can use the nth-child css pseudo selector.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {// For medium displays and above
  .col-sm-4:nth-child(3n+1) { // We target every 3rd div but offset the count by 1 so that that 1st, 4th 7th etc divs are cleared
    clear:both; // Clear the float
  }
}
```

Comment: The 3n+1 doesn't seem necessary, I think it should just be 3n. Otherwise works great, update it or explain why I'm wrong and I'll accept as the answer.

Comment: Beware that this isn't supported in IE8.

Comment: This ain't working for me. Is there another way to fix this issue?